# proving that a group of order 60 is simple using homomorphisms.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I want to show that the group G, where $|G|=60$ and has 20 elements of order 3 is simple.

Here's what I did:

Suppose that G is not simple this implies that $n_3>1, n_2>1, n_5>1$ where these n's denote the number of sylow p-subgroups in G.

Consider $n_5=(1+5k)|12 \Rightarrow n_5=6$ (as we've said it cant be one)

But then $|G:N_G(P)|=6$ ( P denoting the sylow 5 subgroups here).

This implies there is a homomorphism induced by G acting on the left cosets of G/P by left multiplication. $|G/P|>1$ and operation is transitive so the kernel is not the whole group. since g is not simple the map is not injective  and also since the groups are finite not surjective. which implies $|G|>|S_n|$ a contradiction .....so G is simple.

Is this correct ?

If not what specifically is wrong with it ?

Comment: "since $G$ is not simple the map is not injective..." - How does that follow?

Comment: Actually you are assuming not simple, that means there is some normal subgroup either of order 4 or 5

Comment: @Bungo I know that If G were simple then it would be an injective map. maybe what is the true statement is the map may not be injective ?

Comment: Simple $\implies$ injective, but that doesn't mean that (not simple) $\implies$ (not injective), or equivalently, that injective $\implies$ simple.